# PGAdmin 4 not starting in Windows 11

Tags: pgadmin-4, windows-11

I am trying to run PGadmin 4 on Windows 11. Postgres itself is working properly on command line. But while starting PGadmin 4 i am getting the following error.

```
2022-01-11 22:04:00,717: WARNING    werkzeug:   WebSocket transport not available. Install simple-websocket for improved performance.

 * Serving Flask app "pgadmin" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py", line 230, in <module>
    main()
  File "D:\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\web\pgAdmin4.py", line 213, in main
    socketio.run(
  File "D:\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\python\lib\site-packages\flask_socketio\__init__.py", line 596, in run
    app.run(host=host, port=port, threaded=True,
  File "D:\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\python\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 990, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "D:\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\python\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 1052, in run_simple
    inner()
  File "D:\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\python\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 996, in inner
    srv = make_server(
  File "D:\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\python\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 847, in make_server
    return ThreadedWSGIServer(
  File "D:\PostgreSQL\14\pgAdmin 4\python\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 740, in __init__
    HTTPServer.__init__(self, server_address, handler)
  File "socketserver.py", line 452, in __init__
  File "http\server.py", line 140, in server_bind
  File "socket.py", line 756, in getfqdn
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 i`enter code here`n position 0: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Were you able to get this going? Curious if pgadmin is compatible with Win 11 yet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, pgadmin is compatible with windows 11. Is your server running in the background?
From the error message you provided, I think pgadmin is not able to find any server request that needs to be handled, or the port number for Postgress needs to be set to default.